# java.lang.NumberFormatException from parsing a string to a double

Tags: java

I cant figure it out

```
double d = Double.valueOf(str);
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

both methods produce the following exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "‎-73.04"

However, the following hardcoded value works just fine:

`double d = Double.valueOf("-73.04");`

Comment: So the problem is in the content of the string. The dot and/or minus characters are maybe not the same as in your hardcoded example.

Comment: Have you tried to trim your string passed to both methods? It might contains additional characters like whitespace or line return that these methods don't understand.

Comment: i replaced . & - with mine. trim also not help

Comment: im reading data from xls file, some of data is good, but some crashing from some reason

Comment: does your string itself contains double quotes or does it contain leading or trailing spaces ?

Comment: no, it's not contains any char except - & .

Comment: i tried to split by '.' and parse of '04' was good, but the parse of '73' after remove '-', crashing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After copying the number from the title of this question and pasting into IntelliJ between double-quotes, it became clear what the problem is:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("\u200E-73.04");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "?-73.04"
```

Copying it from your hard-coded `-73.04` does not have this behavior.

You have a ["left-to-right mark" Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) in your string somehow.  You must eliminate that extraneous Unicode character from your string before parsing it.